Kernel density estimator in Rstudio. Why do I have NA for bandwidth
I'm analyzing home range of some animals using kernel densities but have run into an issue when determining the h (or bandwidth) value for my dataset. My code uses a loess model to predict the h value. Most of my individuals have run properly and h values were given for each, but three individuals had an h value of NA. What could be causing this?
I'll provide a sample of my code. This is a code created by a previous employee that I am now using so I don't fully understand all of it (it is based on a code by James Patterson jhttps://jamesepaterson.github.io/jamespatersonblog/06_trackingworkshop_reptilekernels).
Create dataframe with MCP area object for all animals
tracking.mcp <- mcp(trackingdatasp, percent = 50)@data
Put reference bandwidths & put in a vector
href <- c()
hpred <- c()
Loop for each individual
  for(i in 1:length(unique(trackingdatasp$ID))){

 Define spatial points
ID <- sort(unique(trackingdatasp@data$ID))[i]
ID.datasp <- trackingdatasp[trackingdatasp$ID == ID,]

# Define href for an individual
kernel.ref <- kernelUD(ID.datasp, h = "href")
href[i] <- kernel.ref[[1]]@h$h

# define limits of h to try
htry <- seq(1, href[i] + 20, by = 2.5) 

# Make a dataframe to hold areas
areatoh.df <- data.frame()

# Now do kernel home range for each of htry
# tryCatch makes sure the loop doesn't stop if there is an error
for(k in 1:length(htry)){
  kernel.try <- tryCatch(kernelUD(ID.datasp, h = htry[k]), error=function(err) NA)
  areatoh.df[k, 1] <- htry[k]
  areatoh.df[k, 2] <- tryCatch(getverticeshr(kernel.try, percent = 50)$area, error=function(err) NA)
  
}

names(areatoh.df) <- c("h", "area")

# First get rid of any wonky values (curves) at low smoothing factors
if(sum(is.na(areatoh.df$area)) > 0){
  last.h <- max(areatoh.df$h[is.na(areatoh.df$area)])
  areatoh.df$area[areatoh.df$h < last.h + 20] <- NA
}

# Try to fix NA values by expanding grid
for(l in 1:length(htry)){
  if(is.na(areatoh.df[l, 2])){
    # Define grid
    # This avoids problems with "grid too small to estimate home range size" (most common kernel issue in R)
    x <- seq(min(ID.datasp@coords[,1]) - 2000,
             max(ID.datasp@coords[,1]) + 2000,
             by = 10.) # resolution is the pixel size you desire
    y <- seq(min(ID.datasp@coords[,2]) - 2000,
             max(ID.datasp@coords[,2]) + 2000,
             by = 10.)
    xy <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
    coordinates(xy) <- ~ x + y
    gridded(xy) <- TRUE
    
    kernel.try <- tryCatch(kernelUD(ID.datasp, h = htry[l], grid = xy), error = function(err) NA) 
    areatoh.df[l, 2] <- tryCatch(getverticeshr(kernel.try, percent = 50)$area, error = function(err) NA)
  }
}
# Construct a loess model to predict area based on h
x <- areatoh.df$area[!is.na(areatoh.df$h) & !is.na(areatoh.df$area)]
y <- areatoh.df$h[!is.na(areatoh.df$h) & !is.na(areatoh.df$area)]
area.h.loess <- loess(y~x)

# Predict the correct h
hpred[i] <- predict(area.h.loess, newdata  = tracking.mcp[i,]$area)
print(hpred[i])
     }
     return(hpred)
     }

reptile50.kd.homerange.fn 50 percent Contour of Homerange
    reptile50.kd.homerange.fn <- function(trackingdatasp, hvector){
      newkernel.poly <- list()
      for(i in 1:length(unique(trackingdatasp@data$ID))){
# Define spatial points layer for an individual
ID <- sort(unique(trackingdatasp@data$ID))[i]
ID.datasp <- trackingdatasp[trackingdatasp$ID == ID, "ID"]

#Create new kernel
newkernel <-  tryCatch(kernelUD(ID.datasp, h = hvector[i]), error = function(err) NA)
# Extract vertices in a list of polygons
newkernel.poly[[i]] <- tryCatch(getverticeshr(newkernel, percent = 50), error = function(err) NA)
if(is.na(newkernel.poly[i])){
  # Define grid
  # This avoids problems with "grid too small to estimate home range size" (most common kernel issue in R)
  x <- seq(min(ID.datasp@coords[,1]) - 2000,
           max(ID.datasp@coords[,1]) + 2000,
           by = 10.) # resolution is the pixel size you desire
  y <- seq(min(ID.datasp@coords[,2]) - 2000,
           max(ID.datasp@coords[,2]) + 2000,
           by = 10.)
  xy <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
  coordinates(xy) <- ~ x + y
  gridded(xy) <- TRUE
  #Create new kernel
  newkernel <-  tryCatch(kernelUD(ID.datasp, h = hvector[i], grid = xy), error = function(err) NA)
  # Extract vertices in a list of polygons
  newkernel.poly[[i]] <- tryCatch(getverticeshr(newkernel, percent = 50), error = function(err) NA)
    }
    }
        return(newkernel.poly)
        }


Are you  getting any  other warnings or errors ?

No errors or warning. When i run my data through my function it just spits out NA

Wherever you end up posting this question, it seems essential that you also include one of the datasets that gives you the NA value given that the code works for most datasets but not the 3 you mention.  In fact, fixing the issue might just need a plot of the coordinates and no code necessary.

You also need to make your code runnable.  For instance, kerneUD isn't a standard part of R, so it requires a definition.

+1 You also need to subset your data to produce a  minimal reproducible example. Careful examination of that smaller data set might reveal the issue immediately (e.g. an NA in the data)
